# How do I spyOn Typescript getters and setters?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, getter-setter

When I unit test my getters are setters for Typescript, I cannot find a way to spy on those getters and setters. Instead, the object immediately gets evaluated. I am using Jasmine to unit test.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879990

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported yet, but there is a Jasmine issue for [supporting getters](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/943).

If you really need the support now, you can extend [SpyRegistry.js](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/SpyRegistry.js) file and add the code that [apsillers](https://github.com/apsillers) proposed:

```
this.spyOnProperty = function(obj, methodName, accessType) {
    ...
    var desc = Object.getPropertyDescriptor(obj, methodName);
    if(desc[accessType]) { // "get" or "set" exists on the property
        var spy = j$.createSpy(methodName, desc[accessType]);  

        desc[accessType] = spy;

        Object.defineProperty(obj, methodName, desc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

`spyOnProperty` is now available in Jasmine:

```
const foop = {
    get value() {},
    set value(v) {}
};

it('can spy on getter', () => {
    spyOnProperty(foop, 'value', 'get').and.returnValue(1);
    expect(foop.value).toBe(1);
});

it('and on setters', () => {
    const spiez = spyOnProperty(foop, 'value', 'set');
    foop.value = true;
    expect(spiez).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: I am trying this,         spyOnProperty(component, 'name', 'get').and.returnValue(1);
        expect(component.name).toBe(1);
But it keeps throwing the error: component.name is not a function

Comment: If the above code doesn't work, try upgrading Jasmine?

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot find a way to spy on those getters and setters. Instead, the object immediately gets evaluated.

That is not supported by Jasmine. Your primary options are to refactor into function calls OR extend jasmine

Comment: I believe it still is not, in 2020. Running into test framework limitations like this is... basically just embarrassing :/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here helpful.  Instead of spying on the getter, just overriding it to modify the return for testing.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26888312/1341825