# Jasmine setter method mock is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular-test

**component.ts**

```
fillformdata(): void {
    if (this.mark === false) {
      var jsoncontent = {
        ipaddr: (this.noip == false) ? this.ipinput : this.ipadd,
        host: (this.noip == false) ? this.hostinput : this.host,
        username: this.usernamevalue,
        password: this.passwordvalue
      };
      this.deployt.setuserinputs(jsoncontent);
    } else {

    }
  }
```

In the above method am trying to set form data to `setuserinputs` which is n depoyClass file

**component.spec.ts**

```
it('should call fillformdata', () => {
    var jsoncontent = {
      ipadd:"127.0.0.1",
      host:"host1",
      username:"admin",
      password:"admin"
    };
    let response = component.fillformdata(); 
    const deploy =  new deploymentdetails();
    const spiez = spyOnProperty(deploy, 'setuserinputs', 'set');
    deployinput.userinputs = [jsoncontent];
    expect(spiez).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(response).not.toBeNull();
  });
```

When am executing `ng test` getting failed. Showing below error

```
Error: <spyOnProperty> : Property setuserinputs does not have access type set
        Usage: spyOnProperty(<object>, <propName>, [accessType])
            at <Jasmine>
```

I have followed below stack link(second answer)
[How do I spyOn Typescript getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576096/how-do-i-spyon-typescript-getters-and-setters)

Comment: can you provide your ts and spec.ts file here which will easy to find out the solution.

Comment: What's `this.deployt`? Please provide the code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to spyOn the component's deploy variable instead.

```js
it('should call fillformdata', () => {
    var jsoncontent = { ... };
    let response = component.fillformdata(); 

    // Spy on component.deployt
    const spiez = spyOn(component.deployt, 'setuserinputs');

    deployinput.userinputs = [jsoncontent];
    expect(spiez).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(response).not.toBeNull();
  });
```