# What version of Jasmine uses Chutzpah? Cannot use spyOnProperty

Tags: jasmine, chutzpah

I just added the latest versions of both Chutzpah and Jasmine NuGet packages to my project.

Besides, I installed the two available Chutzpah Visual Studio extensions (VS2015).

I am trying to use the Jasmine function "`spyOnProperty`", which can be found in the jasmine.js file that the nuget package deploys.

But when I run the test I get an exception:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: spyOnProperty

When I debug, I see that Chutzpah uses a jasmine.js file included in the visual studio extension folder.

How can I tell Chutzpah to use the latest jasmine.js file / jasmine version?

Thanks.

Comment: Chutzpah unfortunately requires its own version of Jasmine which may be out of date. I want to let you customize this but there may be compat issues. For now, which version do you need and I can look to update.

Comment: @MatthewManela According yo this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43793575 Jasmine 2.6.1 is the one that adds the feature spyOnProperty. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @MatthewManela can u please give the current version of jasmine in chutzpah now?