# Angular Unit Tests - how to mock router.url

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular6

I have an angular 6 application and I am trying to unit test a component where I inject the Router. In my ngOnInit method I reference this.router.url and work with it.

So now I am attempting to write a jasmine unit test and I cannot set the router.url property because it "is a constant ot read only property".  I am currently mocking the router like this.

```
mockRouter = jasmine.createSpyObj<Router>("router", ["navigate", "navigateByUrl"]);
```

What else do I need to set to properly mock the url value in my test?

Answer (score 9):

Jasmine spy on property should be reasonable solution

```
spyOnProperty(router, 'url', 'get').and.returnValue('/users');
```

as recommended here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43793575/11552394

and documented in Jasmine docs
https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.4/global.html#spyOnProperty

Comment: i am getting url property dosn't exist error.
Note: url is a read-only property, does it have any effect on spyOnProperty() behavior ?

Comment: define your router object after your describe. then this is what worked for me:

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Router,
          useValue: {
            url: '/page1',
            events: of(new NavigationEnd(0, '/page1', '/')),
            navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
          },
        },
      ],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
    }).compileComponents();

    router = TestBed.inject(Router);

    MockRender();
  });

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me:

```
describe('Yourserviceorcomponent', () => {

...

let router: Router;

...

beforeEach(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Router,
      useValue: {
        url: '/page1',
        events: of(new NavigationEnd(0, '/page1', '/')),
        navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
      },
    },
  ],
  imports: [RouterTestingModule],
}).compileComponents();

router = TestBed.inject(Router);

MockRender();
});
...
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to update the router url afterwards?