# how to get the property of behaivourSubject type property of a service ?, angular testing

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test, angular-testing-library

I have a service like

```
export class TestService {
  public props: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  props$ = this.props.asObservable();

  test(){
  
}

}
```

and this is my .spect file of my component

```
 let component: MainComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainComponent>;
  let testServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<TestService>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    testServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<TestService>("TestService", [
      "test",
    ],);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MainComponent ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      imports:[HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers:[
        {
          provide:TestService,
          useValue:technicalFacilitiesServiceSpy,
          },
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

and when I try to test in my .spect file like

```
  testServiceSpy.props
```

I see undefined,
how could I get the default value? false in this case

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the 3rd argument of `createSpyObj` to mock the public instance variable.

Try doing the following:

```
testServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<TestService>("TestService", [
      "test",
    ], { props$: of(false) });
....
{
   provide: TestService,
   useValue: testServiceSpy
}
```

Check out this link on how to change the instance variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43793575/7365461

Comment: Hi, I see that the method creatSpyObj only receive 2 parameters :(

Comment: Really? It should take 3 and even check out the link I provided. The answer is from the creator of Jasmine.

Comment: Hi, in angular ?

Comment: Yes, using the `jasmine` framework.

Comment: Yes, only allow me add 2 args